# Debugging on Vodafone Smart II

Tags: android, debugging

I want to test my android app on Vodafone Smart II but I'm not able to
connect the device.Do I need a OEM Driver? and which driver is the
appropriate one for that device?

Answer (score 0):

I found the driver here: https://m.box.com/view_shared/rs0qqg1p3grb2xz2m8ad

To find that I just googled for "Vodafone Smart II adb driver" the first match was on xda and the file was linked there...

Comment: I installed that driver, I followed the instructions for Windows 7 from [http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7] but still cannot run my app from the device.. I also have checked the usb debugging in my device.. any ideas?

Comment: Is your device detectable from adb? E.g. does "adb sh echo works" print "works" on you command line?

Comment: "adb sh" prints my adb version and then a lot of commands (i m sorry i m a begginer) and when i put adb devices get the message " adb server out of date .killing  * daemon started successfully * List of devices attached.

Comment: So far if you don't get device not found messages it should work. How do you install your app? Via the play button in Eclipse?

Comment: (Under the list of devices attached there is nothing listed) Yes via the play button..

Comment: This is a little strange... Is there a new unknown device in the device manager when you connect your phone? Do you have SD card sharing enabled? This could cause problems.

Comment: when i connect the device via usb port i get "USB Connection" on my mobile screen and asks to push a button "add USB device" in order to share/copy files between my computer and the device . This is what you mean by saying "Do you have SD card sharing enabled?" ?

Comment: I think so... how ever this feature to share the files with the windows explorer should be disabled.